# Simple ES6 Truncate method for character, word, and sentence limits

Tags: javascript, strings, formatting

Simple truncating method for characters, words, and sentences for a personal utility library I've been working on.

Improvements & criticism welcomed! Especially around default param usage, as I've not utilized it much to date.

```js
const truncate = ((
  value = '',
  int = 0,
  elipsis = '\u2026', /* ... */
  prune = (val, num, at) => val.split(at).splice(0, num).join(at)
) => {
  const sentences = (val = value, num = int, end = elipsis) => prune(val, '.', num) + end;
  const words = (val = value, num = int, end = elipsis) => prune(val, ' ', num) + end;
  const characters = (val = value, num = int, end = elipsis) => val.substring(0, num) + end;
  return {sentences, words, characters};
})();

console.clear();
console.log([
  truncate.sentences("This is a sentence. There are many like it but you won't see the 2nd one", 1, '.'),
  truncate.words("These are words but you won't see what's after this because it'll be hidden", 10),
  truncate.characters("This won't exceed 31 characters so we cutting off the ending", 31, '!')
]);
```

Comment: What does `10` at `truncate.words("These are words but you won't see what's after this because it'll be hidden", 10)` reflect at output? Is `[
  ".",
  "…",
  "This won't exceed 31 characters!"
]` the expected result?

Comment: Looks like i messed up a few things when I renamed the variables and didn't test: https://jsfiddle.net/darcher/j36mzp4w/ <-- original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Review

There was a slight bug in your code. The last two arguments for `prune` were in the wrong order.

You have a lot of duplicated code. Good code is DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

The code is clean and style is consistent.

### Some points

- I can not see the point of arguments as part of the singleton pattern. Not that there's is anything wrong with it, it just seems to add code for no benefit.
- Default parameters should be set at the bottom of the call stack (the function where the arguments are used). This means that you don't need to repeat the defaults each time you pass on arguments and lets you use a shorter syntax.
- You can reduce the source size by moving the three truncate functions into the returned singleton. No need to type their names twice.
- Naming is somewhat poor,

  - Don't name variables by their type. `int` ??? I assume you mean its an integer, but that gives no information as to what it does. Maybe `count`. Don't name variables by their type, that is inferred.
  - `num` ??? LOL again, you are naming for what they are. Name for what the represent. Maybe `count`.
  - `value` Is string or string like, but `value` implies a quantitative like property. A clearer name could be `str` or `string`.
  - `truncate` truncates but internally you `prune` Be consistent when naming different parts of your code. `prune` may be better as `truncate`.

### Design

You are mixing  function roles. Eg `truncate.words` calls `prune` and then appends `end`. Adding `end` is better done in `prune`. When you find yourself repeating code ask yourself why? Am I mixing roles?

Singletons provide great encapsulation, and I think are one of the best ways to maintain a trusted state. However that trust is only as strong as the weakest link. You can add one more level of encapsulation by freezing the singleton you return using `Object.freeze`, it also gives a small increase in performance.

### Rewrite

Less code means less room for bugs. This is part of the DRY philosophy. The aim of the rewrite is to reduce repeated source code.

The first version is not as DRY as it could be (the repeated `(...args) => truncate(".", ...args)`) but there is a point where striving to DRY out code makes it more obscure.

The first example is preferable, the second example is just to demonstrate how code can become less clears as it is compressed.

```js
const truncate = (() => {
  const truncate = (at, str = "", count = 1, end = "\u2026") =>
    (at === "" ? str.substring(0, count) : str.split(at).splice(0, count).join(at)) + end;
  return Object.freeze({
    sentences: (...args) => truncate(".", ...args),
    words: (...args) => truncate(" ", ...args),
    characters: (...args) => truncate("", ...args),
  });
})();



const l=d=>Log.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("div"),{textContent: d}));
l(truncate.sentences("This is a sentence. There are many like it", 1, "."))
l(truncate.words("These are words but you won't see what's after this  foo", 10))
l(truncate.characters("This won't exceed 31 characters so ", 31, "!"))
```

```html
<code id="Log"></code>
```

This example is on the border of too DRY

```js
const truncate = (() => {
  const API = {}, types = [["sentences", "."], ["words", " "], ["characters", ""]];
  const trunc = (at, str = "", count = 1, end = "\u2026") =>
    (at === "" ? str.substring(0, count) : str.split(at).splice(0, count).join(at)) + end;
  types.forEach(type => API[type[0]] = (...args) => trunc(type[1], ...args));
  return Object.freeze(API);
})();


const l=d=>Log.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("div"),{textContent: d}));
l(truncate.sentences("This is a sentence. There are many like it", 1, "."))
l(truncate.words("These are words but you won't see what's after this  foo", 10))
l(truncate.characters("This won't exceed 31 characters so ", 31, "!"))
```

```html
<code id="Log"></code>
```

Comment: This is why I love peer review, really helps to get different perspectives and in this case, greatly elevated information. I really appreciate this feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of `sentences` and `words` appear to be out of order when passed to `prune()`. Not sure why the parameters passed to `prune` are hard-coded at the example, though still passed to `prune()`. Since `words` does not pass a parameter for `at`, `10` is used, which is not the expected result, though can be remedied by defining the parameter `at` at `words` and `sentences` functions, given that each function call expects all three parameters, and `at` is not defined at any of the functions at the code at the question; instead `num` is set to `int`.

Adjusted body of `prune` to include an immediately invoked arrow function to handle the resulting array of `.split()` where delimiter character `!` is not contained in string by checking if the element at index `0` of array is equal to `val`, if true spread `val` to array else use existing array to chain `.splice()` to, then concatenate an empty string or `at` following `.join()` call. At which point the same function can be substituted for `sentences`, `words` and `characters`.

```js
const truncate = ((
  value = '',
  int = 0,
  elipsis = '\u2026', /* ... */
  prune = (val, at, num) => 
            ((s, k = s[0] === val) => 
              `${(k ? [...val] : s)
                 .splice(0, num)
                 .join(k ? '' : at)}${k ? at : ''}`)
            (val.split(at))
) => {
  const sentences = (val = value, at, num = int, end = elipsis) => prune(val, at, num) + end;
  const words = (val = value, at, num = int, end = elipsis) => prune(val, at, num) + end;
  const characters = (val = value, at, num = int, end = elipsis) => prune(val, at, num) + end;
  return {sentences, words, characters};
})();

console.clear();
console.log([
  truncate.sentences("This is a sentence. There are many like it but you won't see the 2nd one", '.', 1),
  truncate.words("These are words but you won't see what's after this because it'll be hidden", ' ', 10),
  truncate.characters("This won't exceed 31 characters so we cutting off the ending", '!', 31)
]);
```

Alternatively, though not consistent with the `sentences`, `words` can be composed with `at` being set as a default parameter

```
const words = ({val = value, at = ' ', num = int, end = elipsis} = {}) => prune(val, at, num) + end;
```

which would be called with

```
truncate.words({val: "These are words but you won't see what's after this because it'll be hidden", num: 10})
```

providing the ability to call the function without explicitly setting and passing `at` as a parameter.

Substituting a single function for `sentences`, `words` and `characters`

```js
const truncate = (
  value = '',
  at = '',
  num = 0,
  elipsis = '\u2026', /* ... */
) => ((val, k = val[0] === value) => 
       `${(k ? [...value] : val).splice(0, num)
          .join(k ? '' : at)}${k ? at : ''}${elipsis}`)
     (value.split(at));

console.clear();
console.log([
  truncate("This is a sentence. There are many like it but you won't see the 2nd one", '.', 1),
  truncate("These are words but you won't see what's after this because it'll be hidden", ' ', 10),
  truncate("This won't exceed 31 characters so we cutting off the ending", '!', 31)
]);
```

Comment: Really good feedback, I can certainly see my shortcomings and like your use of template literals here. I can certainly see the benefit.